# run junit test in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

I use maven, git and netbeans.
In netbeans, there is Other Test Sources folder, in this folder i have src/test/resources.
In this folder, i have a package spring and it contains web-context.xml, service-context.xml and mvc-context.xml

In a junit test i do:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
  "classpath:/spring/web-context.xml",
  "classpath:/spring/services-context.xml",
  "classpath:/spring/mvc-context.xml"})
public class repositoryTest {
...
}

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
class path resource [web-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

how can i run my test?